# How to implement string search in XML`s TextViews in Android Studio?

Tags: android

How to implement string search in XML`s TextView in Android Studio?

Developing a book-type app containing text pages in TextView layout`s XMLs (no SQLite). Need to add a functionality for searching any text string within book pages. Thank you.

Comment: Is the content static, or dynamic? Why is it that you need to search in the TextView's XML vs. the content of the book's pages??

Comment: static content it is actualy a book content, looks like: <TextView
                    ....
                    android:gravity="bottom|left"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                    android:text=
                        "Инсулярный рак щитовидной железы это
редкая злокачественная опухоль, на которую приходится до 2-4% случаев всех
аденокарцином ЩЖ. у"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Should I use WebView or a database instead? it was a wrong approach to the app design? Is there any tutorial for a book-type app? Thx